# Setting Portrait and Landscape in one place in Android

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am trying to set Orientation in one place such a way that if Tablets it should show the activities **ONLY in LANDSCAPE** mode and if phones it should show **ONLY in PORTRAIT** mode.

Is there any way to do it?

I know I have put this particular code in all screens it would do the job for my requirement:

```
if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL)
        {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL)
        {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)
        {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
else
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
```

but the problem is I have like nearly 25 activities. It is really boring to copy and paste the above lines in all of them.

Let me know!

Comment: Copy and paste is not only boring, but also a maintenance nightmare. At minimum put that into a method that is called several times. It may also be possible to define a common base class for your activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Class which will extend `AppCompatActivity` and your activity classes will extend this new class.

**Example:**

**OrientationClass.class:**

```
public class OrientationClass extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
           setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {
           setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
           setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        } else {
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    }
}
```

**YourActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends OrientationClass {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have to still do the copy and paste. Anyways, this is better than my logic.